# using external Definitions in Swagger / Zircote / Nelmio-api-doc

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I use following versions:

```
zircote/swagger-php in version 2.0.10
nelmio/api-doc-bundle in version v3.0.0-BETA4
```

My Controller with one Action

```
    /**
     * @Operation(
     *     tags={"DeliverySlip"},
     *     summary="Send information after deliveryItems are processed and deliverySlip was scanned",
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="Returned when successful"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="400",
     *         description="Returned on a missing request parameter"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="500",
     *         description="Returned on any other error"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *        name="slipIdentifier",
     *        description="identifier of delivery slip",
     *        type="string",
     *        format="string",
     *        in="path"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *        name="JSON update body",
     *        in="body",
     *        description="json login request object",
     *        required=true,
     *        @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/product")
     *     )
     * )
     *
     * @Put("/deliveryslip/update/{slipIdentifier}", requirements={"slipIdentifier" = "\w+"})
     *
     * @param string $slipIdentifier
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function updateDeliverySlipAction($slipIdentifier, Request $request)
```

This is the Model/Definition I want to use in my Controller-Action:

```
<?php

namespace Sendis\Presentation\RestBundle\Model;

use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;

/**
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *     definition="product",
 *     type="object",
 *     required={"name"}
 * )
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @SWG\Property(example="doggie")
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;
}
```

But when I go to my documentation page at /api/doc, I see this error:

```
Errors
Resolver error at paths./api/deliveryslip/update/{slipIdentifier}.put.parameters.1.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: #/definitions/product
```

The next thing I recognised: 
My **product.php** does not seem to be read by `swagger` at all. I can write whatever I want here. No errors, even if I misspell something. This brings me to the conclusion, that my **product.php** was not found by `swagger` at all.

I am helpful for every hint.

Kind regards,
Max

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem. I needed to load the external definition with its full namespace like so:

```
/**
     * @SWG\Put(
     *     path="/deliveryslip/update/{slipIdentifier}",
     *     tags={"DeliverySlip"},
     *     summary="Send information after deliveryItems are processed and deliverySlip was scanned",
     *     @SWG\Definition(
     *        definition="product",
     *        type="object",
     *        required={"name"}
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="Returned when successful"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="400",
     *         description="Returned on a missing request parameter"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response="500",
     *         description="Returned on any other error"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *        name="slipIdentifier",
     *        description="identifier of delivery slip",
     *        type="string",
     *        format="string",
     *        in="path"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *        name="JSON update body",
     *        in="body",
     *        description="json login request object",
     *        required=true,
     *        @SWG\Schema(
     *         type="array",
     *         @Model(type=Sendis\Presentation\RestBundle\Model\Product::class)
     *     )
     *     )
     * )
     *
     * @param string $slipIdentifier
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function updateDeliverySlipAction($slipIdentifier, Request $request)
```